# Is it possible to post/append to a google spreadsheet with just an api key?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been reading the docs extensively for sheets v4. I'm trying to post form data to a google spreadsheet with just the apikey (not using oauth). I don't want clients/users to have to login to be able to fill out my form.

[The docs indeed](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) says oauth only. Is there no way around this? Is there anyway to send a simple form's data to a google sheet?

This is the code I'm trying.

```
const postURL = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1GOSI8dDYmuBIznSV-Ge9WtY_RSivo6rEpnpC8EZDnuw/values/orders!:append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=RAW&key=mykey`;

   let opts = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // "range": 'orders',
        "majorDimension": 'ROWS',
        "values": [
          this.state.email
        ],
      })
    }


      e.preventDefault()
        fetch(postURL, opts)
          .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
          .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))


  }
```

Comment: You can certainly write an Apps Script webapp that takes the form input and then writes it to a Google Sheets file. You would have the webapp deployed to execute as you. Without an oauth-authorized intermediary like the webapp there is no way to write to Google Sheets programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use POST and PUT using API key. On the other hand, GET method can be used by API key. It is considered that it due to the security. So you can achieve it using tehhowch's proposal and/or [the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters, you can't. You can only GET with the api key. Darn!

But, here's a pretty good guide on how to submit forms using a script on the spreadsheet side:

https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets